# How to finetune a QA model on Huggingface without the Trainer class?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have the following inputs:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

model_name = "deepset/roberta-base-squad2"
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)


QA_input = {
    'question': 'Which magazine was started first Arthur's Magazine or First for Women?',
    'context': 'Radio City is India's first private FM...'
}
```

I'm trying to finetune it on [this dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/hotpot_qa) **without the Trainer class**.

I found [the tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/7?fw=pt) but they use the `Trainer class`.

Currently what I have is:

```
tok = tokenizer(QA_input['question'],QA_input['context'], return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**tok)
answer_start_scores = outputs.start_logits
answer_end_scores = outputs.end_logit
>>>
answer_start_scores tensor([[ 2.1691, -6.0923, -8.1997, -7.6676, -8.6942, -7.5250, -9.1025, -8.4655,
         -5.9657,  2.0334,  0.5248, -1.1092, -0.6666, -1.2680, -2.7834, -4.1984,
         -6.5456, -6.9495, -3.6798, -5.9952,  4.6541,  4.0024, -3.1714, -1.7563,
         -1.5274, -2.7023,  2.4152, -2.4580, -1.1586, -1.2393, -4.4350, -3.3643,
         -2.0520, -7.1857]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>)
answer_end_scores tensor([[ 2.7784, -6.9623, -8.1543, -8.6904, -7.3144, -6.7994, -6.7297, -5.1045,
         -0.8470, -5.2608, -3.8302, -6.5672, -6.2452, -4.8464, -6.8564, -6.7473,
         -2.1737, -7.3393, -4.9755, -0.6742, -2.4742,  2.7718, -2.6973, -3.3356,
          4.6363, -1.5485, -4.1409, -3.7737, -2.6754, -2.3832, -2.8759,  4.5230,
          3.6473, -2.1456]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>)
```

However, the remaining steps are unclear to me as the dataset has the answer as a string, and I couldn't find a way to get a differentiable loss from the answer string to the start/end scores.

Comment: How does the `Trainer` class operates to do this ? Out of personal curiosity, why don"t you want to use the `Trainer` class ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about how the Trainer class is doing it. The tutorial goes through how to plug in things and then some unknown magic happens (unless you want to dig through the source code). The trainer class seems to be optimized to work with batches and for my use case I need to get a loss for one sentence/ context at a time